# No puedo leer un correo a través de Servidor de gmail

Tags: java

No puedo leer un correo a través de [Servidor de gmail](http://www.chuidiang.org/java/herramientas/javamail/leer-correo-javamail.php), la cual esta configurado como **pop.gmail.com** pero en el programa que tengo no me deja conectarme.

> Servidor de correo (hay un requisito que no puedo tener alcanze de mis
>   manos)

- Deshabilitar TLS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

/**
 * Class reads emails
 * 
 * @author itcuties
 * 
 */
public class JavaMailReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readEmails(false);
    }

    /**
     * Method reads emails from the IMAP or POP3 server.
     * @param isImap - if true then we are reading messages from the IMAP server, if no then read from the POP3 server.
     */
    private static void readEmails(boolean isImap) {
        // Create all the needed properties - empty!
        Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
        // Create the session
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(connectionProperties,null);

        try {
            System.out.print("Connecting to the IMAP server...");
            // Connecting to the server
            // Set the store depending on the parameter flag value
            String storeName = isImap ? "imaps" : "pop3";   
            Store store = session.getStore(storeName);

            // Set the server depending on the parameter flag value
            String server = isImap ? "imap.gmail.com" : "pop.gmail.com"; 
            store.connect(server,"algo@gmail.com","ritmo");

            System.out.println("done!");

            // Get the Inbox folder
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");

            // Set the mode to the read-only mode
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            // Get messages
            Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();

            System.out.println("Reading messages...");

            // Display the messages
            for(Message message:messages) {
                for (Address a: message.getFrom())
                    System.out.println("From:" + a);

                System.out.println("Title: " + message.getSubject());
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(message.getContent());
                System.out.println("---");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

> Error:

```
    Connecting to the IMAP server...javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: Connect failed
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:209)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at com.itcuties.java.JavaMailReader.readEmails(JavaMailReader.java:42)
    at com.itcuties.java.JavaMailReader.main(JavaMailReader.java:20)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connect failed
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:127)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:260)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:205)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Mira esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34615950/4092887) o busca `javax.mail.messagingexception failed to connect to imap.gmail.com` en Google. Saludos